# How to call workbook/worksheet with app script - fully qualified reference to

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am first time app script user, I have used vba in excel a lot but am struggling with app script a bit.   All I want to do simply create a variable that stores the fully qualified reference to a worksheet so that I can perform various tasks with data in that worksheet.    All examples I see online only reference active worksheets.

I have tried the script below but I get error that it cant find function getActiveSheet().  I am sure I am missing something obvious here.

```
  var sales_file = DriveApp.getFileById(range.getCell(3, 2).getValue()); 
  var sales_sheet = sales_file.getActiveSheet().getName();
  Logger.log(sales_sheet)
```

in the end I want a variable I can use to copy data from the worksheet into another as well as

Comment: You are combining methods that don't go together.  There is no `getValue()` method of the file class returned by `DriveApp.getFileById()`  In the documentation, make sure to look at what is returned by the method.  Use: `var sales_file = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567");` to get the spreadsheet file.  Then you'll need to get a range in the spreadsheet, and then you can get a value from the range.  So, I wouldn't use `DriveApp` to get the spreadsheet file.  If you were going to do file operations that SpreadsheetApp couldn't do, that's the only reason to use DriveApp.

Comment: Please, take a look at the [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/) - especially `getFileById()` method for `DriveApp` (upd: Alan Wells was first - very detailed explanation of your issue)

Comment: Why not just bookmark it?